# Adding textview in childview layout of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview, baseadapter

I have expandableListview which is working fine, but Now in childview I have to make it bigger and add more information in a sense that I need to add more textview respective to each child vertically. For example the layout for child view should be something like this

```
Type 1       Value1
Type 2       Value2
Type 3       Value3 

Category     Average
```

I already have this category and average but now need to sub types and respective values.

To achieve this I am trying to inflate new layout having two textview and then add to child view. but It is over lapping the information I do not know how to make it vertical.
I am sharing piece of code which is trying to do this.

```
  @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder.sub_rl = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_row_layout);
        holder.cat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_row_cat);
        holder.avg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_row_avg);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.sub_row_layout, holder.sub_rl);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.sub_row_cat, holder.cat);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.sub_row_avg, holder.avg);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else
       if (getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).type.equals("Emp")) {

                    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++){
                        Log.d(TAG, "coming ");
                        LayoutInflater inflater2 = null;
                        inflater2 = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View mLinearView2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.type_layout, null);
                        LinearLayout wifi_layout = (LinearLayout) mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.type_layout);
                        TextView mSubItemName = (TextView) mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.row_type);
                        TextView sub_value = (TextView) mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.row_value);
                        mSubItemName.setText("Sub Text "+ i);
                        holder.sub_rl.addView(wifi_layout);

                    }

                    if (getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).cat.isEmpty()) {
                        if (getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).cat != null && holder.cat != null)
                            holder.cat.setText("(Hidden Category)");
                    } else {
                        if (getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).cat != null && holder.cat != null)
                            holder.cat.setText(getChild(groupPosition,  childPosition).cat);
                    }
                    if (getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).avg != null && holder.avg != null)
                        holder.avg.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).avg);
 return convertView;
}
```

list_item.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:id="@+id/es_child_main"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/sub_row_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sub_row_cat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sub_row_avg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/sub_row_cat"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

any suggestion would be nice...or better approach Thanks

Comment: post your list_item.xml code

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest use linear layout or better table layout for your need for child layout like this, it's working for me:

```
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Type 1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Value 1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Type 2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Value 2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Type 3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Value 3" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: but I dont get your point, why I should use table layout for my main layout which is list_item?\

Comment: To get the result as you have posted below line 'For example the layout for child view should be something like this'. If I am not wrong, you want that three lines in single child view right?